# Woocommerce Products Appearing in Wrong Categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Has anybody had any experiences with Woocommerce products displaying in unrelated categories on the front-end? On the back-end the product has been linked to the correct category, but when I go to the front-end of the website, it is displaying in 2 categories. Please can someone help?

https://www.recordmad.co.za/shop/
Click on New LPs - You will see the "10cc – How Dare You!" record there.
Click on Secondhand LP's - You will see the "10cc – How Dare You!" record there.

In the back-end it is only linked to Secondhand LP's, so why is Woocommerce putting it in both?

It is not a theme issue, there is no database caching and I have tried changing the slugs of the categories as well with no luck. Anybody experienced this before?

Kind Regards
Kyle

Comment: 10cc – How Dare You! had two categories (Rock and Secondhand LPs). Can you please check it again? If you assigned a subcategory (I mean second-level category), WordPress might take top level and second level categories both. Check categories listing for this product in the admin section.

Comment: The problem is that when we assign it to SecondHand LP's it puts it in New LP's as well which are two totally different categories not parent or linked to each other in any way. Even if we just assign the record to "Rock" only under Secondhand LP's, it assigns it to New LP's :(